# Configure multiple emails for Serilog.Email sink based on log level

Tags: email, serilog, asp.net-core-2.2

In my asp.net core 2.2 project (C#), I want serilog to use different sinks depending on the log level.  For example, for every level below warning I want to write to a sql database. For Warning I want to send email to warn@domain.com and for error and above I want to send an email to error@domain.com.

googled a bunch of different "serilog different email", "serilog email log level". Nothing relevant comes up.

In my startup.cs file (asp.net core 2.2 project):

```
         Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
           .Enrich.FromLogContext()
           .Enrich.WithMachineName()
           .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"], "censor_logs", columnOptions: columnOptions, autoCreateSqlTable: true)
           .CreateLogger();
```

in appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
   "MinimumLevel": "Warning"
}
```

Would like log.Warn to go to an email sink to a particular email address
log.Error and above to go to another email link
and
all log activity (including those above) to go to a sql database. Right now, I just get all log levels warn and above to SQL.